# Builder error: final does not name a type

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to configure eclipse to use C++11.
In project properties I added the argument `-std=c++0x` as suggested in some discussions on the Internet.

Neverthless, the compiler still complains:

```
21:23:06 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project prova ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/ProvaClasse.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"src/ProvaClasse.d" -MT"src/ProvaClasse.d" -o "src/ProvaClasse.o" "../src/ProvaClasse.cpp"
In file included from ../src/ProvaClasse.cpp:8:0:
../src/ProvaClasse.h:16:21: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
../src/ProvaClasse.h:16:23: error: ‘final’ does not name a type
make: *** [src/ProvaClasse.o] Error 1

21:23:06 Build Finished (took 63ms)
```

Eclipse version is Kepler.
OS is Linux Mint 13.
g++ version is 4.6.3.

And here's the class

```
#ifndef PROVACLASSE_H_
#define PROVACLASSE_H_

class ProvaClasse {
public:
    ProvaClasse();
    virtual ~ProvaClasse();

    virtual void prova() final;
};

#endif /* PROVACLASSE_H_ */
```

Comment: "use C++11." "gcc 4.6.3." Don't even try. 4.6.3 is old and its c++11 support is very incomplete.

Comment: @n.m. do you mean that I shouldn't use C++11 or that I should update gcc and try again?

Comment: If you want to use C++11 -- which imho is a good idea -- then upgrade your gcc to a version which supports it. If you want to use C++11 and your compiler only accepts `--std=C++0x`, that should give you a hint that something is not quite right.

Comment: You can either give up on c++11, carefully use a very limited subset of c++11, or update gcc (to 4.8.2 perhaps). I would update gcc if I could but of course it's up to you.

Comment: @n.m. then I will upgrade gcc, thank you!